# Is there a way to keep a single url, domain, or ip, for communication between docker containters, and between localhost and containers?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I am working on a web app where a single environmental variable is used for specifying a certain server (a rest api), like this:

.env:

```
...
URL_SERVER_API="http://localhost:8080"
...
```

the application is running inside a container, and it uses the server api variable for two things related to my problem:

1. It could generate and serve dynamic html where it append URL_SERVER_API to complete full api urls, for example {{URL_SERVER_API}}/someendpoint
2. It calls the api directly from a (php) script using CURL, defining the endpoint in the same fashion as 1

so I end up with a situation where if I set URL_SERVER_API to localhost:8080 the main application forms valid urls to call because the api app (which is also running in a docker container) was exposed in the correspondingly port, but the CURL calls don't work because localhost:8080 is not a known server inside the container.

Also I configured a bridge network and attached both apps to it, and I was capable to ping from the main app to the api succesfuly (e.g. ping api_docker), then when I set URL_SERVER_API=api_docker the CURL calls to the api are successfull, but the html files returned from the main app are constructed with unreachable urls like http://api_docker/someendpoint

Hope you can see my issue

I am able to solve the issue by having two variables URL_SERVER_API and URL_SERVER_API_INTERNAL and using the first for html serving and the second for the CURL calls, but I think it is not the best solution to add new variables to remember because I am not in charge to do so.
Thanks for the time taken to read

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can use `host.docker.internal:8080` in both containers.

Comment: Having a separate "internal" and "external" configured name is reasonably common here; the standard Apache Kafka messaging system images come to mind as one place where that's configured.  You can imagine other situations like hosting your application on a CDN of some sort where the two names will necessarily be different.

Comment: @jcragun I don't think `host.docker.internal` will work from a browser and it definitely won't work from another host.